# Google Plus not able to redirect to application after sharing in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

the issue is in sharing of some thing using google plus in iOS application. the login works fine of google plus in my and google provided demo.

when i implemented it back 2 months it worked fine but suddenly i checked it today it gives error.

1) when i try to share some thing it redirects me to safari as expected. in both case when i am trying to login.
2)but when i press share button it shows sharing dialogue and after that it redirect to new page and error comes like "about:invalid#zClosurez"

3)but when it opens safari for login and i authorise app and it redirect me to my app back perfectly.

4)sharing is working fine the things that user wants to share is shared but it does not redirect back to my app.

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=794&can=8&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
click for detailed question

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have anyone found it's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug Google's side with the page that was redirecting the user back - it was fixed in a release this week, so you shouldn't see the issue any longer.